# Moving window over large raster map

Tags: python, dictionary, arcgis

What is the best way to resample a 11000 x 13000 cells raster image? I would want to recalculate every cell using the values of all cells within a circle of x meters. It is similar to a convolution, but the calculation will differ each run.

I could well work this out by exporting the map to an ascii format such as asciiGrid, but I do hope ArcGis provides a better way of realizing it.

The desired result would look something like this:

```
for y in lyrYrange:
  for x in lyrXrange:
    window = lyr.getWindow(x, y, sizeX, sizeY)
    newlyr[x, y] = DoMyProcessing(window)
```

The unknown part here is what function to call instead of the fictitious "getWindow()".

Comment: Not possible with just arcgis to my knowledge, might be some function with raster math that can do it. Best bet is probably to use arcpy with conversion to numpy array.

Comment: The memory-demand is too great for this approach.

Comment: 11k x 13k image only takes up about 1,1gb ram. Most machines have enough memory for that.

Comment: You could try to create something in modelbuilder that takes a cell, create a square polygon around it, and clips the raster on the polygon. And then run the processing on the resulting clipped raster and assign the value to the cell. Using the tools from spatial analyst should make this doable. But it's probably gonna be painfully slow.

Comment: The first one, i.e. the source raster, i can open all right. The second one, which is a numpy array of the same dimensions, triggers the memory problem. That is on a 8Gb machine with Windows7X64. I have tried the model builder, but I found better at home with a programming environment. And MB certainly isn't racing indeed.

Comment: Are you using a 64 bit version of python? The standard that ships with arcgis is 32 bit, and wont allow you to use much memory. esri has a 64 bit patch\update available, so you can use arcpy with 64 bit python. "arcgis 64 bit background geoprocessing" search for that and you'll find it.

Comment: I think you might be right there. Default I use the 64 bit, but within the ArcGis realm it seems to be a 32 version. I'll see to changing that. Thanks.

Comment: @user508402 Hi, did you solve this problem? I'm in search of a way to read large rasters (15G+) by a moving (or sliding, or rolling) windows. But I haven't succeed yet. I'm aiming to do this with python, and numpy (memmap? maybe, If I only could the right way to do it). Tell me how you doing.

Comment: @Delonix R: I have not. I am working around the problem by exporting the map to ascii-grid and subsequently processing in Dephi, or by doing the whole thing in IDL

Comment: @user508402, there are raster-to-numpy and numpy-to-raster tools. I'm trying to take a patch of the raster with raster-to-numpy. Numpy allows to treat rasters as row,column values. Process it and then use numpy-to-raster. So far works fine, but a leak in memory prevents my code to process the hole raster. Lets keep in touch to see how this progress.